# How to get and set shipphone for transaction shipping address in SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to retrieve and modify the shipping address shipphone value when an item fulfillment is saved, but the changes do not save (and I have not figured out how to retrieve the shipphone so I was doing initial testing with the phone value). Is there another way that I should be doing this so that I can actually update the transaction-level address details? I am assuming that I need to load the customer record to get the address since I cannot directly get the phone on the transaction record, but that still doesn't explain how I can set shipphone for the shippingaddress on a transaction.

```
function beforeSubmit(context) {
    var ifNum = 'N/A';
    if (context.newRecord.id) ifNum = context.newRecord.id;

    var recordPhone = context.newRecord.getValue('phone');
    var phoneValid = checkPhone(recordPhone);

    if (!phoneValid) {
        try {
            var correctedPhone = correctPhone(recordPhone);
            var shipaddress = context.newRecord.getSubrecord('shippingaddress')
            shipaddress.setValue({fieldId: 'shipphone', value: correctedPhone});

            log.debug('Set phone to: ' + correctedPhone + ' from ' + recordPhone);
        }
        catch(e) {
            var errorStr = 'Error setting IF #' + ifNum + ' phone value';
            log.error(errorStr, e.message);
            throw error.create({
                name: errorStr,
                message: e.message,
                notifyOff: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shipphone` is a transaction body level field for transactions that have it (sales order, item fulfillment etc)

the address subrecord field that it is sourced from is `addrphone` so your code should likely be more like:

```
var recordPhone = context.newRecord.getValue({fieldId:'shipphone'});
...
  context.newRecord.setValue({fieldId:'shipphone', value:correctedPhone}); // for this transaction
  shipaddress.setValue({fieldId: 'addrphone', value: correctedPhone}); // corrected for future uses of this address.
```